# which method is best for Bulk Insert?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

i have to insert more than 200k records in sqlserver DB.

My idea is to add the data into DATA TABLE then doing Bulk Insert, but my TL said: "insert the data into CSV file format and do the bulk insert".

Which approach is faster?

Comment: Using [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is the most efficient way. But you haven't said what is your original data source.

Comment: Why do you think it would be faster to write a C# program that creates a data table, populates it, then inserts? I think your TL was on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CSV file has already been created [SQL Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) is by far the fastest in both performance and development time.

If your creating the data in your application you'll most likely find [BulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to be the easiest/fastest solution.

Either way 200k records is not a huge amount of data and should be fairly fast.

Answer (score 2):

Usually bulk inserting csv file is high performance insertion

```
BULK
INSERT Table
FROM ‘$path\$file.csv’
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ‘;’, 
    ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\n’,
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    TABLOCK
)
```

I agree with **Tim Schmelter** the answer may vary depending of your data source.